# Need advice regarding POST in PHP security

Tags: php

A have a PHP script ("process.php") which extracts the value of volts sent (using GET) and saves it into database when I type this into the address bar:

```
http://127.0.0.1/process.php?v=210
```

There will be 4-5 clients that will such data to the server.

What should I do to make the logging process secure ?

I have thought of authenticating each client before data is logged in the database. Also, can this be also possible that, the PHP script cannot be downloaded by any user it should only process the parameters sent to it.

Comment: http basic authentication?

Comment: If volts is always going to be an integer I would suggest casting it as such too to reduce the likelihood of SQL injections

Answer (score 0):

PHP can not be downloaded by any clients. Its executed on the server and sends an HMTL response. I would add some authentification parameters to your adress string. To me, this would be the easiest, but not the most secure solution.